# $getJson always return 404

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my jquery call to get a json response from my own server.

```
 $.getJSON('rocket/'+i, function(data) {
            data= JSON.stringify(data);
            localStorage.setItem('lvlJson'+i, data);
        });
```

When i go to the url on my server ( https://thinkstar.fr/rocket/1 ) the json response is well returned.

I have set in my php server some cors precaution in case (even if i'm calling from my own web page):

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://thinkstar.fr/');`

I'm still getting 404 on every request.

If you have an idea don't hesitate to tell me thanks !

Note: The problem does not occur during my local development

[image: network error1]

[image: network error2]

As you can see on the two pictures above , the request has the json response but is still considered as 404

Comment: Try adding a forward slash to the front of the URL - e.g.$.getJSON('/rocket/'+i

Comment: @Chris thanks for your answer , i tried but doesn't work . I think that's not a url format problem. When the console log display 404 i can go to the link and get the json...

Comment: Look at the network tab in Chrome and see the error there.

Comment: @AndyRay As weird as it seems , the preview and response has the json content but the status code is 404. I don't know if it's linked to cors policy or others stuff

Comment: It's because the server is returning an HTTP status code of 404 even though it has the data. The server is misconfigured to not send the right HTTP code. If you don't control the server, you can ignore the HTTP status code.

Comment: @AndyRay Thanks for your answers , i have control on the server and the controller return the json as it do on my local ,  i even tried to force a 200 code status but the problem is persisting ... https://github.com/chiptu/JeuLogique/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/RocketController.php

Comment: Just a guess, but it looks to me like Nginx sets the status code based on whether there exists a file at the "path" part of the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution :

Thanks to Andy Ray

The problem in my case is due to nginx configuration.

I have a nginx ubuntu laravel configuration, in my case :

add

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

to

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.com**

and execute :

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Normally query will not return 404 anymore.